# What is necessary to allow the [Authorize] attribute to work in a VS 2019 Web API?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have created a web api using VS 2019. It is a Core 3.1 and is published to Azure. I have selected "Authenticate" during the creation to allow "School and Work" IDs.

After I create API, and with no modifications made to the code generated by VS, there is a single controller (weatherforecast) with the [Authorize] attribute. If you run the API from the debugger and test the API on my local IIS Express, the browser returns an unauthorized message. In fact, if you place a Break in the default controller, the controller code is never reached after a call to it.

However, if I comment out the [Authorize], I can easily reach the controller and the "weatherforecast" is returned to the browser.

I suspect that the template generated code for the API to use [Authorize] is incomplete. Maybe a package, service in the pipeline of the Startup.cs, or other configuration. I'm surprised that the default template doesn't work without modification but whatever.

What do I need to get the [Authorization] attribute to work in this scenario? I would like to use MSAL for my authentication and to pass this token to the controller to get user information among other things.

Comment: You need to do **a lot** more than just creating the project. You need to set up your app in Azure Active Directory and config your application accordingly. Look for a tutorial (perhaps something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/)

Comment: Yes of course, for brevity I didn't include that I successfully published to Azure App Services, made sure the Registered App connected correctly to the API and that there was also an Enterprise app. The problem is that the code within the controller is never reached despite all that. I have included Users, manifests...I should be able to debug this locally too. I can't figure out what I'm missing

Comment: Those are important bits, they should be in the question. Last time I touched AAD was 2 years ago, so it might have changed, but AFAIK you need one app/config per environment (local is one URL, deployed is another)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code to your API:

**Startup.cs:**

***Configure method:***

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

***ConfigureServices method:***

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
              {
                  options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              })
                .AddJwtBearer("ADB2C", jwtOptions =>
                {
                    jwtOptions.Authority = $"{appConfiguration.AppSettings.Adb2cInstance}/{appConfiguration.AppSettings.Adb2cDomain}/{appConfiguration.AppSettings.Adb2cPolicy}/v2.0/";
                    jwtOptions.Audience = appConfiguration.AppSettings.Adb2cClientId;
                    jwtOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = bool.Parse(configuration["AppSettings:RequireHttpsMetadata"]); //// NOTE:: This is set only for dev purposes. Remove for higher environments.
                    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = arg =>
                        {
                            // invoked if authentication fails
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    };
                }));
            
            services.AddAuthorization(options => 
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().AddAuthenticationSchemes("ADB2C").Build();

                options.AddPolicy("B2C", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().AddAuthenticationSchemes("ADB2C").Build()); });
```

**DummyController.cs:**

```
[Authorize(Policy = "B2C")]
public class DummyController : Controller
    {
```